# Name of measurement expressed as the sum of different units

Tags: terminology, units

In a paper I'm writing, I want to make a comment about errors in an old paper made when doing arithmetic with measurements expressed as as the sum of quantities with two or more different units, for example 5 pounds 11 ounces, or 3 minutes 20 seconds 17 seconds.  Is there a standard name for such values?  I'm sure there must be but I can't think of it, and have no idea what to search for to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called *mixed units*.